# Possible reason: Same CSS but Different Result

Tags: css

I am trying to modify one WordPress theme http://demo.wpzoom.com/evertis/ and use it on my own site.

However, something weird occured, the footer area will not display properly with **Firefox** (while it works fine on IE8):

[image]

The original theme works fine on Firefox and IE8.
[image]

Whats the possible reason?

More Information: I am using Notepad++ with Encoding "UTF-8 without BOM." Many years ago, I saw a problem similar to this one with IE6, after I change the Encoding to "ANSI", everything is fine. But this time it wont work.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I changed almost nothing. I didnt change the css "footer" area for sure.

Comment: I'd also ask what have you changed - but you might also try looking at your theme through Firebug, see if there are other margins that those footer-sections might be inheriting. You might also be able to get that last section to snap up if you slighly reduce the right margin on ALL of them (or also override the margin-right on that last footer section, like @Lokase said below.)

Comment: @Lokase method works. But I still dont know why this happened. I have installed WebDeveloper plugin on my Firefox, which I think is better than Firebug. The CSS is the same.

Comment: Pro Tip: Web Developer and Firebug are both essential, it is not either or, if using Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

Try overriding the margin-right on the last footer section, something like:

```
.wpzoom-flickr-photos { margin-right:0; }
```

Comment: WOW! SO is a place full of genius! Thanks but I want to know why. The CSS and the html code are alomost the same, I edit almost nothing. Why it wont work on my local browser? How I can prevent this in the future?

Comment: You say almost nothing, you clearly changed something of key import

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the display: inline-block which is known for having issues. Here is an article where you could find the answer you are looking for:

http://blog.mozilla.org/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/